# How to redirect subfolders to new domain but not root?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm redirecting site to the new domain with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Code is working but problem is that I want to redirect all subfolders but not root, for example:

I want to redirect:
olddomain.com/some-folder -> newdomain.com/some-folder

but not
olddomain.com -> newdomain

I want to redirect the root with 404 to newdomain.com

Reason for that is that newdomain.com is already existing for couple of years and I want to turn off olddomain.com and redirect all articles to new one and root with 404.

If somebody have a better proposition let me now.

Thank you

Comment: Make your match, `^(.*)$` require something, by using + instead of *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but your RewriteRule says match 0 or more characters (`*`) and rewrite, you want 1 or more characters (`+`).  Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

*Remember, your browser might have cached some of the redirects; so don't be surprised if you need to clear your cache, or load up another browser to test this.*

Comment: Can you tell me what should I do with olddomain? Should I redirect old domain with 404 to new one or something else?